# why is my custom loop failing?

Tags: conditional-content

I have a custom post type to get images. I am setting up my theme to display a specific way when it is first installed. For some reason, my code is stopping the bottom half of my page from displaying.

```
 <div id="gallery">
    <?php if( $loop->has_posts()): ?>
    <hr />
    <h1 class="tag-background"><span class="background">FROM THE GALLERY</span></h1>
    <ul>
    <?php
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
           <li><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('frontpage_gallery'); ?></a> </li>
                 <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
        <?php endif; wp_reset_query();?>
</div><!--END gallery-->
```

When I view source, the only part of the gallery div that shows above is the opening div. Everything after that including the footer is gone. This happened when I put all the gallery stuff between the if statement. What am I missing?

```
 if( $loop->has_posts()):

 endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is `$loop->has_posts()`. Try `$loop->have_posts()`.

Comment: I am such a dork. I should have seen that. Thanks. That fixed my issue

Comment: We've all been there. Sometimes all it takes is a second set of eyes!